# PyQt5 - Duplicate GUI when multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm attempting to multiprocess the saving for my application. For some reason, when I spawn a pool, a duplicate of my GUI pops up. The GUI pops up on this line and the program doesn't push images onto the pool until I tell it, so the internals of the process shouldn't matter. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it does this. Any help?

`self.save_pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)`

Comment: Impossible to tell without code, but you've probably ignored `multiprocessing`'s absolute requirement that there be no top-level code outside of an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: Sure enough, I had forgotten to wrap the Qt application exec in ````if __name__ == "__main__":```` For some reason it is still acting like nothing has been applied to the pool, but that's a separate issue. Thanks!